# fragment shader with SNORM textures

Tags: opengl, textures, glsl

I want to apply SNORM texture by using GL_TEXTURE_3D as a target, what will be the fragment shader for the same?
Also, what should be the data type of texture data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `RGBA_SNORM` you should use `GL_BYTE` with four components per texel to fill it.

It is basically the same as normal UNORM textures only that you get a value between `-1.0` and `1.0` when sampling. 
The signed byte value is mapped -127 -> -1.0 and +127 -> 1.0. -128 is dropped.

Sampler type is sampler3D (Floating-point also covers normalized integer formats).

Comment: isampler is used for signed integer textures. so i am just confused between sample3D and isampler3D.

Comment: can you tell me why can't we use isampler3D here?

Comment: The samplers result is not an integer, its a float. If you want an integer you should use an integer texture format instead of a normalised one. Eg GL_RGBA8UI for an unsigned integer between 0 and 255.

Comment: When I use glbyte with sampler3d. Values less than 127 are taken as 0 and renders black for it, works correctly with 127

Comment: Values less than 127 represent negative numbers in a SNORM (signed normalized) texture. Negative numbers get clamped to 0->black when you write them into a unsigned render target eg the back buffer.

Comment: So if I want intensity half of max what will be the value for it??

Comment: 191, are you sure you need a SNORM texture if you do not understand what SNORM actually does? You are throwing away half of your precision when you do not need negative values

Comment: You told to use gl_byte, range of which is -127 to 127.  So hw will 191 will work out??

Comment: Oh, yeah. Sorry, I was a little "out of this question". Of courseit is 64 with BYTE. Hmm, strange. What do you mean by 127 works correctly? Is it fully white?

Comment: Here are the specs: [EXT_texture_snorm](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/texture_snorm.txt). It says that `GL_BYTE` is filled `max ( <c>/(2^7-1), -1.0 )`. Filling it with `GL_UBYTE` is only possible for positive numbers, everything above 127 is cut.

Comment: 127 is fully white when used as GL_Byte, but below 127 is black.

Comment: That does sound like it is clamped. You sample it using a sampler3D and store the result in a vec4?

Comment: yes, i tried that on Nvidia card. Surprisingly, when i try GL_byte with sampler3D on ATI card it gives black color.

Comment: If you still need help you should add example code, it should work this way.